# spring data jpa @Query with enum type not returning data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Here goes. Logs show no records returned.

> 14:10:01.331 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Registering statement [SELECT inspector.* FROM inspector inspector WHERE inspector.mailState IN (?, ?)]
>   14:10:01.331 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Registering last query statement [SELECT inspector.* FROM inspector inspector WHERE inspector.mailState IN (?, ?)]
>   14:10:01.331 DEBUG Loader - bindNamedParameters() UNREAD -> stateList_0_ [1]
>   14:10:01.332 TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - [UNREAD]
>   14:10:01.336 TRACE SerializationHelper - Starting serialization of object [UNREAD]
>   14:10:01.336 DEBUG Loader - bindNamedParameters() BLOCK_FAILURE -> stateList_1_ [2]
>   14:10:01.337 TRACE BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - [BLOCK_FAILURE]
>   14:10:01.337 TRACE SerializationHelper - Starting serialization of object [BLOCK_FAILURE]
>   14:10:01.337 TRACE Loader - Bound [3] parameters total
>   14:10:01.338 TRACE JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Registering result set [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@41f0527f]
>   14:10:01.338 TRACE Loader - Processing result set
>   14:10:01.338 TRACE Loader - Done processing result set (0 rows)
>   14:10:01.338 TRACE Loader - Total objects hydrated: 0

Table definitely has a record with 'UNREAD' in the mailState column. JpaRepository using spring data jpa has the following code

```
@Query(value = "SELECT inspector.* FROM inspector inspector WHERE inspector.mailState IN :stateList", nativeQuery = true)
List<Inspector> findAllByState(@Param("stateList") List<MailState> stateList);
```

My Inspector class is as such

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inspector")
public class Inspector {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "mailState")
    private MailState state;

    //...getters and setters etc...

    public enum MailState {
        UNREAD("Unread"),
        BLOCK_SUCCESS("Block Success"),
        BLOCK_FAILURE("Block Failure");

        private final String value;

        MailState(String v) {
            value = v;
        }

        public String value() {
            return value;
        }

        public static MailState fromValue(String v) {
            for (MailState c: MailState.values()) {
                if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this returning no records when I can clearly see a record and hibernate loads up the enums for the query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a native query instead of a JPQL query, which would use the mappings defined in your entity to use the appropriate types and bind the enums correctly. Replace your query with a JPQL query:

```
@Query("select inspector FROM Inspector inspector where inspector.state in :stateList")
```

Comment: Didn't work 100% but you were on the right track. I just needed to reference the object field (state) and not the database field (mailState) in the JPQL query you provided. Thanks. I'll mark as accepted as soon as you edit.